# How to decompress the gz files in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have 5 files called test1.gz, test2,gz....test5.gz in C:\CompressFiles and I want to decompress them and load them in other folder C:\DecompressFile. I tried using Exceute process task and script task in ssis (visual studio 8), but no luck. Is there is any work around for that? Any  help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00f110d9-9be8-481c-9696-75be9973e728/how-do-you-unzip-a-file-in-an-ssis-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices

This can be a good starting point. Pick one method that suits you. If you get stuck, let us know. Good luck!